# Getting IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type even after changing to integer type

Tags: python

I am having problems with this code

```
Indexlist=d.get_star_slice()
for i, index in enumerate(Indexlist):
    index=int(index)
    if data[('sigma')][Indexlist==index]<3:
            s = AbuSet[(d.ions, d.data[index], molfrac == True)]
            Z=s.elements_Z() 
            eps = s.elements_log_eps()
```

and am having issues with the s=AbuSet[(d.ions... line. Originally it did not have the square brackets so I was getting 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable but after adding the brackets in I get the error: IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type and I can't seem to find a way to fix it.

So far I have checked the dtypes and the d.ions is an object and d.data[index] is float64. I change the line to this to try to change the float64 to int

```
s = AbuSet[(d.ions, d.data[index].astype(int), molfrac == True)]
```

but still get the same error.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to call a function, but it's not clear what the function you're trying to call is.